# How can I expose two JAX-RS resources with the same path inside a WAR

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

In WAR file I add 2 different JAR that has JAX-RS resources. 
I add a ResourceConfig subclass to register all resources from this 2 JAR.
But in these two JAR one resource has the same name. Is it possible to change the pathname from the register method in ResourceConfig class, or any other way in which I can change the path of the resource and give it to another name?

I can not create multiple @ApplicaionPath.

In JAR 1:

```
@Path("product")
public class ProductApi(){
    ......
}
```

In JAR 2:

```
@Path("product")
public class ProductApi(){
    ......
}
```

In WAR

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class MainAPi extends ResourceConfig {
    packages(jar1.apis);
    packages(jar2.apis);
}
```

So the conflict is with `ProductApi`. Only one is in effect because it shares the same path `/api/product`

So how to route from `MainApi` to the different `ProductApi`?
or is any other way around to change it without modifying JARs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reference from 
[https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e10848](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e10911)

```
Resource jar1ProductApi = Resource.builder(Jar1.ProductApi.class).path("newpath/product").build();
registerResources(jar1ProductApi);
```

I add this to main ResourceConfig File and now onwards it calls via new URL route(newpath/product)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to define two `ResourceConfig`:

```
@ApplicationPath("api1")
public class MainApiOne extends ResourceConfig {
    packages(jar1.apis);
}

@ApplicationPath("api2")
public class MainApiTwo extends ResourceConfig {
    packages(jar2.apis);
}
```

So, `/api1/product` accesses the resource in JAR 1, and `/api2/product` accesses the resource in JAR 2